# $L\text{- Lipschitz } (L>0) \text{ function } f(x) \iff f(x) \text{ is monotonically increasing }$?

Tags: definition, lipschitz-functions, monotone-functions

Probably a very basic question: Let's assume that we have a $L$-Lipschitz ($L>0$) function $f(x)$. Can we say the following?:
$$
L\text{- Lipschitz } (L>0) \text{ function } f(x) \iff f(x) \text{ is monotonically increasing }
$$

Comment: Isn't the map $x\mapsto x^3$ a counterexample?

Comment: Neither implication stands.

Comment: Indeed, thank you both @SylvainJulien and Gae.S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt[3]{x}$ is monotonically increasing but not Lipschitz continuous. $\sin x$ is Lipschitz continuous but not monotone.